# How to fix not able to use setOnQueryTextListener in SearchView

Tags: android

I can't use setOnQueryTextListener with my SearchView. Here is my code:

Gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

menu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/searchView"
          android:title="Action Search"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
```

```
val searchView = menu?.findItem(R.id.searchView)?.actionView
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener
```

setOnQueryTextListener is highlighted red. I can't seem to find any answer regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it as `SearchView`. Without cast it is a normal `View`

```
//import androidx version of SearchView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

//cast actionView as SearchView
val searchView = menu?.findItem(R.id.searchView)?.actionView as SearchView?
searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener
```